# How to display style inheritance information in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-styles

Earlier this evening I found that if I pressed control and moved the cursor over a style, for example over the `ActionBar` in

`<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">`

then a new window opened on the RHS of the screen showing the inheritance structure of the style (`ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar`) and attributes modified with colors displayed.

Something then changed and now click/hover does nothing.

Where is the option for this in Settings? I can't see any reference to the feature or how to switch it on again. I'm using Android Studio 3.3.1

Answer (score 1):

I found this is a Quick Documentation (View > Quick Documentation) window. It also appears in some situations as you type, in my case typing a line like this:
`app:titleTextAppearance="@style/MyTextAppearance`. It can (obviously) be opened in many other places in code.

You can then click the gear bottom right on the Quick Documentation window to 'Open as tool window'. Then in `styles.xml`, for example, you can move the mouse over style parents, press control, and see the documentation. I didn't know that!